# How to make search faster in mysql DB with > 2m records, only numbers

Tags: mysql, php

I have a table with sim card data with over 2m-3m records.

The design is a column sim_number = varchar(11) with data like number (0123456891)

When the table is under 1m records it's still fast but when over 2m it takes more time to search

1. Search by:

   - LIKE '%6789%' take about under 1s
   - LIKE '%567891%' take about 2s
2. Search a full number like (WHERE sim_number = '0123456891')

   - With the number as the last record take about 2-3s

My VPS has 2GB RAM

Can this performance be improved?

I tried to use full text search with this table but it's not working because there is no word in my search.

Comment: Create an ordinary index on sim_number column. That will make searches of the form WHERE sim_number = '0123456891',  WHERE sim_number LIKE '01234%' fast. Searches with WHERE sim_number LIKE '%6789%'  will always result in a full table scan, hence they cannot be made "fast". Use InnoDB if you don't already and set innodb buffer pool large enough so that the entire table and its indexes fit into it.

Comment: please provide your table structure using `SHOW CREATE TABLE SimCard` and also your complete query

Comment: A couple of points.  What does "With the number as the last record take about 2-3s" mean? There is no such thing as a first or a last record in an RDBMS. Secondly, you say that there is "no word in my search". A "word" is just a sequence of characters - you can call '123' a "word" if you wish.

Comment: With only 2GB of RAM, things are tight.  Suggest you shrink fields wherever possible.  Is a `sim_number` always 11 _digits_?  If so, use DECIMAL(11) instead of `VARCHAR`; it will take only 5 bytes.

Comment: So now i've only one problem that's how to use like '%34567%' faster. Thanks for all support! @Rick James: my data alwy contain '0' at the first char! With innodb_buffer_pool config, can make my search faster?

Comment: `DECIMAL(11) ZEROFILL` will reconstruct the leading zero(es).

Comment: For 2GB, innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 400M.  Leading '%' in LIKE cannot be sped up; it will scan the entire table.  Encourage users to avoid leading wild card.